# Use static library using Qt in MFC application

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, qt6

I have written a library that uses Qt6 and I need to use the code inside of a massive legacy MFC project. However, when I try to inlude the directory and use one of the headers from my library, the Qt part is not being recognized.

The MFC project is set up using Visual Studio Solutions.

I have a added the Qt extension to Visual Studio and have tried including the Qt include directories (i.e ...include/QtCore, ...include/QtGui etc.) When doing so I get the error...

`static_assert failed: 'On MSVC you must pass the /permissive- option to the compiler.'`

... followed by a large amount of errors regarding QtCore shared pointers.

However, when setting the \permissive- flag on the MFC project, I receive an uncountable number of errors from the MFC project, many regarding non-acceptable conversions with old C-type arrays etc. I have a fear that a lot of the legacy code is in a very bad state.

How am I supposed to go about this, if it is even possible? Is the solution to go fix all the error from the MFC project, or am I missing something when including Qt?

Comment: Qt is as hostile as any given library can be. There's not a snowflake's chance in Hell to incorporate Qt's idea of implementing a GUI into *any* Windows GUI program without losing your sanity. The only viable option is either ditching MFC or ditching Qt. If you insist on using Qt, you will want to wrap it behind a well-defined interface boundary, such as [ActiveX](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-activex.html).

Comment: I am not trying to implement a Qt GUI next to MFC, but I guess that is not really the point, the problem is the same. I was afraid that this would be the case. I guess I have to stick with calling the Qt Application as a stand-alone application. Thanks for the insights.